# Why am I getting an import error when I import utils?

Tags: python, package

I have been trying to import util, process_methods etc from utils.

```
from utils import util as U
```

When I run this it gives me this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'util' from 'utils' (D:\Anaconda\lib\site- 
packages\utils\__init__.py)
```

I have installed utils. Please help me out

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! People will be able to help you if you provide all of the details, including the error message. See How do I ask a good question? Also, try to use the title to sum up the question and not to ask for help. You should explain better what you are trying to do on your description.

Comment: looked at their [Github](https://github.com/haaksmash/pyutils/tree/master/utils), could not find `util` most likely its typo. pls check if you are importing the right module.